# Prevent Windows from installing display languages

Tags: windows-7, language

I run Windows 7 Ultimate x64. During Windows Update, a ton of random languages get installed, which takes up tons of storage space and takes forever. I removed them but they keep getting re-installed during Windows Update. How do I prevent this from happening? I've done some searching but all I find is how to install additional languages, not prevent their installation. This only happens on my Ultimate PC, not on my Professional.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the Windows Update panel and click the **"Change Settings"** button on the left panel. Change it from **"Automatically Install Updates"** to **"Check for Updates but Let me Choose When to Download and Install Them."** This should prevent them from being installed automatically. Hope this helps!

Comment: I have it set for manual approval but the languages get installed anyway. The updates don't go themselves, but the languages do once I start the updates.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up having to "Hide" all those updates. I'm not sure why they came as needed/wanted but I had to hide them. I will probably have to run updates manually to make sure they don't come back into the active list.